# Code working outside of function but not inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am having problems applying a function to my dataframe because it is returning an error:

```
----> 8     return data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
KeyError: 'duration'
```

I have the function:

```
def calc_dist(row):
    lat = centroid['Latitude'][row]
    lng = centroid['Longitude'][row]
    base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=place_id:{}&destinations={},{}&key=xxxxxx"
    url = base_url.format(datas.place_id, lat, lng)
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    return data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
```

When I run the code inside the function by itself it works fine, and it returns the api call that looks like

```
{'destination_addresses': ['50 W 20th St, New York, NY 10011, USA'],
 'origin_addresses': ['LaGuardia Airport (LGA), Queens, NY 11371, USA'],
 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '9.4 mi', 'value': 15134},
 'duration': {'text': '28 mins', 'value': 1653},
 'status': 'OK'}]}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

Here is my apply if it is of any use

```
centroid['distance'] = centroid.apply(calc_dist, axis=1)
```

Centroid is a dataframe that contains two columns longitude and latitude

Edit:
I fixed it I changed the line where I done the apply to

```
centroid['distance'] = centroid.apply(lambda row: calc_dist(row['Latitude'],row['Longitude']), axis=1)
```

and I changed the function to

```
def calc_dist(lat,lng):
    base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=place_id:{}&destinations={},{}&key=xxxxxx"
    url = base_url.format(datas.place_id, lat, lng)
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    return data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
```

Comment: It looks like there are some lines (it could be as few as one single line) in your dataframe for which the request to the API is returning something your function is not expecting. Maybe put in some exception handling to help you work out which lines are failing. Then you can try those out 'by hand' and see what's going on.

Comment: simply use `print( data['rows'][0]['elements'][0] )` to see what you get. And `print( row )` to see for which row you get wrong values.

Comment: @furas I done that and its giving me a status not found so I guess there is a problem with my function or apply where its not properly getting the latitude and longitude

Comment: use `print()` to see what values you have in variables which you use in function.

Comment: Could you please add an example of input to the function, and what it produces, so one could easily reproduce the issue?